# Which Office 365 plans does include SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

The page [Compare Office 365 Business Plans](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/compare-office-365-for-business-plans) shows you the Office 365 business plans. But it doesn't tells you which plan includes SharePoint Online. I know that Office 365 Business Premium does include SharePoint Online because I have the trial version.

So please tell me which Office 365 Business Plan include SharePoint Online.

EDIT:
Perhaps "Team Sites" on [this page](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-business-essentials) refers to SharePoint Online?

EDIT:
I found this blog post: [Comparing features in SharePoint Online across Office 365 Service Plans](http://blogs.technet.com/b/lystavlen/archive/2012/05/10/comparing-features-in-sharepoint-online-across-office-365-service-plans.aspx). It is from May 2012, so it is a bit outdated. Plans have changed from Kiosk, Small Business and Enterprise to Business Essentials, Bussines and Bussines Premium. So I guess all Office 365 plans include SharePoint Online. Do you know a page with updated info on this?

Comment: Not 100%, but the Enterprise plans use the same language (Team Sites), and they definitely come with SPO, so I'd say yes.

Answer (score 3):

I just checked the O365 catalog, alle Enterprise plans include SharePoint. The following O365 plans include SharePoint according to the O365 catalog:

- Enterprise E1, E3, E4
- Business Essentials, Business Premium, Business

If you just want SharePoint, you can also subscribe to SharePoint Online Plan 1 or 2.

The URL for the catalog: https://portal.office.com/catalog